# Firebase functions not being resolved (Cannot resolve "FirebaseInstanceIdService")

Tags: android

So I'm trying to use Firebase Cloud Messaging for my app but when I try to test it, even the sample code throws me an error.

```
public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

/**
 * Persist token to third-party servers.
 *
 * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
}
}
```

Any function that refers to the Firebase API isn't found, as if I hadn't included it yet. Here's my app gradle:

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
 compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here's my project gradle:

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
     jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
     jcenter()
 }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here're my hunches on what might be wrong:

1. Check if on top of file you have this line:

`import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;`

2. If you're using Android Studio, go to:
   `Tools  -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`
   And see if it helps.

Comment: Oh man! I was so frustrated with it not working that I didn't remember to put that back! Thank you so much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ionic cordova platforms remove android
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
ionic cordova platforms add android
```